# Редактор CSV файлов на python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть файл csv с колонкой price.
В этом фрагменте я открываю его и записываю значения с колонки price в массив:

```
import csv
def csv_reader(file):
   prices = []
   reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
   for row in reader:
      prices.append(row["prices"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(FN) as file:
        csv_reader(file)
```

Дальше эти значения корректируются. Новые значения нужно записать обратно в csv. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: советую ознакомиться с [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) - там это делается одной-двумя строками и без использования циклов.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

fn = r'/path/to/file.csv'
xchange_rate = 0.88  #  курс USD --> EUR

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=',')
df['prices'] *= xchange_rate
df.to_csv(fn, index=False)
```

или одной строкой:

```
(pd.read_csv(fn, sep=',')
   .eval("prices = prices * @xchange_rate")
   .to_csv(fn, index=False))
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Все работает